# open new form or edit current form

Tags: c#, forms

I am starting a C# application for windows desktop machines.

I am wondering what the best method for my scenario would be.

I have 2 simple forms, one will have a couple of buttons which will be the main start form.  The second form will have some labels and text fields that will be filled in with a scanner.  I will be trying later to accept entry only from the com port so whoever is using it doesnt have to select the program to have it get input.  After the last textbox in the second form is filled right the program goes back to the first form.

I was thinking of showing the new form and hiding the main one but i was thinking it would be best in one window.

I am very new to C# so this is learning experience for best practice.

Thank you

Comment: You could probably explore TabControl and create two tabs as your two virtual windows. The other Tab (let's say Tab1) would be disabled not until the entry of other Tab (let's say Tab2) is completed. Then that's the time the other Tab (i.e. Tab1) is enabled and ready for interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure what king of information you want, but given "I am very new to C#", I'll give you information that I think I would have needed to know when I was "very new to C#".

I'd personally recommend not using windows forms and going with **WPF**. It allows you to make fully customizable applications and to add a lot of features (especially visual features) to your application that would not be possible using `Forms`.

In the case of using `WPF`, you'd probably have one window, and two separate `UserControls`.
Depending on how complicated this application might be, you should consider using a **pattern** like `MVVM` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx); the more complicated you might expect your application to get, the more I'd recommend using it.

In the case of using `MVVM`, both of your `Forms` (I'll refer to them as `UserControls`), would each have some `DataContext` set. The `DataContext` would be a class that the view (your `UserControl`) would bind to. So the idea is that you might have methods in this `ViewModel` (the `DataContext`) that would fill its members with the data from the COM port, and the View (the `UserControl`) would have bindings to its `DataContext` (`ViewModel`) that would indicate the data in the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` would also have the responsibility of notifying the View when a value has been updated so it can show it. Properties on the ViewModel can also be updated(via bindings) to indicate that something has been changed by the user on the `UserControl`. So, for example, your `Textbox` might be bound to a `String property`, so that when the `String property` changes, the `Textbox` updates. Similarly, when the text in the `Textbox` changes, the string property would be updated. This is all customizable. The idea is that there is a clean separation between the `View` and `ViewModel` so that stuff is easy to test and not as likely to break.

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but I hope this helps!!

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Edper, This is a great starting point.  I have not considered WPF so i will look into that